# How to set id via data field in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Here is part of my code:

```
- @search_trees.each do |search_tree|
        %ul
          = link_to search_tree.getname(search_tree.designation_id), {:controller => "search_trees", :action => "catalog", :cat => search_tree.STR_ID}, :class => 'catalog-click', :id => search_tree.STR_ID
```

As you can see, i'm setting class and id for link, but how to set id for %ul tag? something like this %ul#=search_tree.STR_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finded answer by myself (if anybody have better solution, give it please):

```
%ul{:id => search_tree.STR_ID}
```